# Problem with my form and search interacting with my jquery code for a city weather search

Tags: jquery, html

I have written code to search for todays weather using Open Weather Map. I am able to make the code work when the form and button is in the body. But when I copy and paste that code into the navbar area, it does not work. I am 100% sure this is developer error, but I wanted to see if anyone could point out where I am going wrong.

To make this easier, I have included a link to my codepen:  https://codepen.io/rob-connolly/pen/wvawLOy

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitWeather').click(function() {
    var city = $('#city').val();
    if (city != '') {
      $.ajax({

        url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=34fd31758b449ea433e05058c225793c&q=' + city + "&units=imperial&count=10",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
          var widget = show(data);

          $("#show").html(widget);

          $("#city").val('');
        }

      });
    } else {
      $("#error").html('Field cannot be empty');
    }
  });
});

function show(data) {
  return data.city.name + ' (' + data.list[0].dt_txt.split(' ')[0] + ') </h3>' +
    '<p><strong>Temp: </strong>' + data.list[0].main.temp + ' degrees</p>' +
    '<p><strong>Humidity: </strong>' + data.list[0].main.humidity + ' %</p>' +
    '<p><strong>Wind Speed: </strong>' + data.list[0].wind.speed + ' MPH</p>';
}


console.log('hello')
```

```css
.mainArea {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.day1,
.day2,
.day3,
.day4,
.day5 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.input {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type='text'] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation Bar -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <!-- this is the form for the weather search-->
        <form class="weatherSearch form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="city" type="search" placeholder="Search City" aria-label="Search">
          <button id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-8'>
        <!-- Thi is the div id = show to display the weather data. -->
        <div id="show">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container'>

      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-2 day1' id="show1">
          hello</div>
        <div class='col-2 day2'>
          hello </div>
        <div class='col-2 day3'>
          Hello </div>
        <div class='col-2 day4'>
          Hellp </div>
        <div class='col-2 day5'>
          Hellp </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Content -->




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your search button submits your form and reloads the page. Try changing the submit button's type to button instead of submit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a form with Jquery and button for submitting the form. This should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation Bar -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <!-- this is the form for the weather search-->
        <div class="weatherSearch form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="city" type="search" placeholder="Search City" aria-label="Search">
          <button id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-8'>
        <!-- Thi is the div id = show to display the weather data. -->
        <div id="show">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container'>

      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-2 day1' id="show1">
          hello</div>
        <div class='col-2 day2'>
          hello </div>
        <div class='col-2 day3'>
          Hello </div>
        <div class='col-2 day4'>
          Hellp </div>
        <div class='col-2 day5'>
          Hellp </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Content -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer as "The problem is that you are using a form with Jquery and button for submitting the form." doesn't mean anything

Comment: compare the html here with yours.. you have form with button submit.. and I've changed your form with simple div..

Comment: You will need to have form-handler which is typically a server page with a script for processing input data, for example process.php which will process your input data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent form from submission. Here is your pen working correctly https://codepen.io/bigbadmytyx/pen/poJzMjY

I added this:

```
$("#submitWeather").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

It prevents form from sumbission, fires ajax request instead.